# Link NFT Collection to Opensea

Tags: solidity, nft, opensea

Hi super basic question as I am new to NFT dev (currently learning solidity).  Looking to make a super basic NFT project with website, art, and link to Opensea in secondary market (no roadmap, just a learning experience for me and probably giving NFTs for free).  I understand that you can make a candy machine that allows users to mint on website, but I'd like them to be able to view and trade their nfts on a secondary marketplace like Opensea.  How would I go about doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: Candy machine is Solana, Opensea is Ethereum and Polygon. Any ERC721/ERC1155 token on ETH/Polygon can be traded on Opensea

Answer (score 0):

After minting nfts, they can be view and trade on Opensea and do not need additional actions.

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, you don't need to do anything to actually have them in Opensea, except to deploy your SC.

I think this could be very useful to you https://buildspace.so/p/mint-nft-collection if you are just beginning and new. It's a well explained tutorial, and you can see there how this would work for you to see it in opensea.

Hope that helps.